# What formulas to use to model a shock-wave propagation?

Tags: physics, mathematical-modeling

I'm a first year physics student. I want to make a simulation that models the Tunguska explosion. I want to specify the energy and position of the blast in air and then to somehow model the propagation of that shock-wave. Where can I find the equations that could help me model the distribution and propagation of the shock-wave (I presume that it would be sufficient to track the change of the scalar field representing air pressure?).

Comment: Look up Rankine-Hugoniot conditions.  Wikipedia also has a decent page on shock waves.

Comment: @bob.sacamento Thank you! :)

Comment: See also: [Chapman–Jouguet condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapman-Jouguet_condition).

Comment: @Geremia Thanks! ^^